# How to select contents of element with jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax/windowshop.php',
        context:'#windowShop',
        success:function(data){
                        $('#windowShop').append(data);

                    }
            })
```

I want to select the contents of #windowShop from the page ajax/windowshop.php and insert them into an element on the current page. I can't find much documentation on context when using the ajax command and this doesn't seem to work because data contains the whole page 'ajax/windowshop.php' and not just the contents of ('#windowShop') in ajax/windowshop.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the content from the `data` coming back.  For example if all of the main content is in a div with `id="content"` you could grab that...

```
success: function(data) {
   $('#windowShop').html($(data).find('#content').html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'ajax/windowshop.php',
    context:'#windowShop',
    success:function(data){
        $(this).append($(data).find('#idOfElement'));
    }
});
```

Comment: This still loads all of the content from the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load` with a selector like this.

```
$('#windowShop').load('ajax/windowshop.php #windowShop');
```